# QLineEdit Password - Obscure All But Last Character

Tags: qt, passwords, qlineedit

We are using a QLineEdit for password entry, with echo mode set to 'Password'. A request was made to obscure all characters typed except for the last, an entry feature I've seen on some smartphones.

How would I go about implementing such a thing?

Comment: I would bet to standard echo mode + reimplementing apriopriate protected methods (Own class derived from QLineEdit).